# Debugging in Python: Show last N executed lines

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I would love to see the last 10 lines which were executed by the python interpreter before this exception occured:

```
test_has_perm_in_foobar.py F
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../test_has_perm_in_foobar.py", line 50, in test_has_perm
    self.assertFalse(check_perm(request, some_object))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 416, in assertFalse
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: True is not false
```

I want to see where `check_perm()` returned `True`.

I know that I could use interactive debugging to find the matching line, but I am lazy and want to find a easier way to the line where `check_perm()` returned the return value.

I use pyCharm, but a text based tool, would solve my need, too.

BTW: Please don't tell me how to use the debugger with step-over and step-into. I know this.

Here is some code to illustrate it.

```
def check_perm(request, some_object):
    if condition_1:
        return True
    if condition_2:
        return sub_check(some_object)
    if condition_3:
        return sub_check2(some_object)
    ...
```

There are several ways where `check_perm()` could return `True`. If `True` was returned because of condition_1, then I want to see something like this

```
+         if condition_1:
+            return True
```

The output I have in mind is like `set -x` on the shell.

## Update

cgitb, pytest and other tools can show the lines before the line where the assertion failed. BUT, they only show the lines of the current python file. This question is about the lines which were executed before the assertion  happens, but covering all files. In my case I want to know where the return value of `check_perm()` was created. The tools pytest, cgitb, ... don't show this.

What I am searching is like `set -x` on the shell:

> help set
>
> -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find a solution, I wrote this myself:

```
with trace_function_calls():    
    self.assertFalse(check_perm(request, some_object))
```

Implementation of trace_function_calls():

```
class trace_function_calls(object):
    depth_symbol = '+'

    def __init__(self, write_method=None, log_lines=True):
        '''
        write_method: A method which gets called for every executed line. Defauls to logger.info

        # Simple example:

        with debugutils.trace_function_calls():
            method_you_want_to_trace()
        '''
        if write_method is None:
            write_method=logger.info
        self.write_method = write_method
        self.log_lines = log_lines

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old = sys.gettrace()
        self.depth = 0
        sys.settrace(self.trace_callback)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        sys.settrace(self.old)

    def trace_callback(self, frame, event, arg):
        # from http://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html#tracing-function-calls
        if event == 'return':
            self.depth -= 1
            return self.trace_callback

        if event == 'line':
            if not self.log_lines:
                return self.trace_callback
        elif event == 'call':
            self.depth += 1
        else:
            # self.write_method('unknown: %s' % event)
            return self.trace_callback

        msg = []
        msg.append(self.depth_symbol * self.depth)

        co = frame.f_code
        func_name = co.co_name
        func_line_no = frame.f_lineno

        func_filename = co.co_filename
        if not is_python_file_from_my_codebase(func_filename):
            return self.trace_callback
        code_line = linecache.getline(func_filename, func_line_no).rstrip()
        msg.append('%s: %s %r on line %s of %s' % (
            event, func_name, code_line, func_line_no, func_filename))
        self.write_method(' '.join(msg))
        return self.trace_callback
```

PS: This is open source software. If you want to create a python package, do it, tell me, it would make me glad.

Answer (score 4):

For this reason I've switched testing to [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/).

It can show local variables and traceback with different detalization level. Line where call was done is marked with `>`.

For example in my  django project:

```
$ py.test --showlocals --tb=long
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-3.0.3, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0
Django settings: dj_tg_bot.settings (from ini file)
rootdir: /Users/el/Projects/dj-tg-alpha-bot, inifile: tox.ini
plugins: django-3.0.0, cov-2.4.0
collected 8 items

tests/test_commands.py ....F
tests/test_logger.py .
tests/test_simple.py ..

==================================== FAILURES =====================================
__________________________ TestSimpleCommands.test_start __________________________

self = <tests.test_commands.TestSimpleCommands testMethod=test_start>

    def test_start(self,):
        """
            Test bot accept normally command /start and replies as it should.
            """
>       self._test_message_ok(self.start)

self       = <tests.test_commands.TestSimpleCommands testMethod=test_start>

tests/test_commands.py:56:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <tests.test_commands.TestSimpleCommands testMethod=test_start>
action = {'in': ' /start', 'out': {'parse_mode': 'Markdown', 'reply_markup': '', 'text': 'Welcome'}}
update = <telegram.update.Update object at 0x113e16cf8>, number = 1

    def _test_message_ok(self, action, update=None, number=1):
        if not update:
            update = self.update
        with mock.patch("telegram.bot.Bot.sendMessage", callable=mock.MagicMock()) as mock_send:
            if 'in' in action:
                update.message.text = action['in']
            response = self.client.post(self.webhook_url, update.to_json(), **self.kwargs)
            #  Check response 200 OK
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
            #  Check
>           self.assertBotResponse(mock_send, action)

action     = {'in': ' /start', 'out': {'parse_mode': 'Markdown', 'reply_markup': '', 'text': 'Welcome'}}
mock_send  = <MagicMock name='sendMessage' id='4619939344'>
number     = 1
response   = <Response status_code=200, "application/json">
self       = <tests.test_commands.TestSimpleCommands testMethod=test_start>
update     = <telegram.update.Update object at 0x113e16cf8>

../../.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telegrambot/test/testcases.py:83:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <tests.test_commands.TestSimpleCommands testMethod=test_start>
mock_send = <MagicMock name='sendMessage' id='4619939344'>
command = {'in': ' /start', 'out': {'parse_mode': 'Markdown', 'reply_markup': '', 'text': 'Welcome'}}

    def assertBotResponse(self, mock_send, command):
>       args, kwargs = mock_send.call_args
E       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

command    = {'in': ' /start', 'out': {'parse_mode': 'Markdown', 'reply_markup': '', 'text': 'Welcome'}}
mock_send  = <MagicMock name='sendMessage' id='4619939344'>
self       = <tests.test_commands.TestSimpleCommands testMethod=test_start>

../../.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telegrambot/test/testcases.py:61: TypeError
------------------------------ Captured stderr call -------------------------------
Handler not found for {'message': {'from': {'username': 'username_4', 'last_name': 'last_name_4', 'id': 5, 'first_name': 'first_name_4'}, 'chat': {'username': 'username_4', 'last_name': 'last_name_4', 'first_name': 'first_name_4', 'title': 'title_4', 'type': 'private', 'id': 5}, 'text': ' /start', 'message_id': 5, 'date': 1482500826}, 'update_id': 5}
======================= 1 failed, 7 passed in 2.29 seconds ========================
(.env) ✘-1 ~/Projects/dj-tg-alpha-bot [master|✚ 1…8⚑ 12]
16:47 $
```

Comment: I use pytest, too. Yes it shows the line before the line where the assertion failed. But only of the current file. If there is an assertion which checks the return value of a method call, then you don't see where the return happened. That's what my question is about. I know this is hard to explain.If you know how to write my question better, please let me know.

Comment: I understand your idea to gather all data from previous side calls. But it seems to me it goes more to debugging rather that to testing. What if cover them with unittests to get sure they are working well?

Answer (score 1):

What about `cgitb`? You just need import this module to your code.

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable(format='text')

def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    x = 0
    d = a * b * c / x
    return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f()
```

Gives:

```
ZeroDivisionError
Python 3.5.2: /usr/bin/python3
Mon Dec 19 17:42:34 2016

A problem occurred in a Python script.  Here is the sequence of
function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.
 /home/user1/123.py in <module>()
   10     d = a * b * c / x
   11     return x
   12 
   13 if __name__ == "__main__":
   14     f()
f = <function f>
 /home/user1/123.py in f()
    8     c = 3
    9     x = 0
   10     d = a * b * c / x
   11     return x
   12 
d undefined
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
x = 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
...
The above is a description of an error in a Python program.  Here is
the original traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123.py", line 14, in <module>
    f()
  File "123.py", line 10, in f
    d = a * b * c / x
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Yes, I like the output of cgitb (and the django debug page). I guess these don't give me the information I am looking for. In my case I don't get an exception. The method returns a value. But where did the actual value came from? I updated the question to illustrate what I want. Nevertheless thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#programmatic-interface) module has bourne compatible shell `set -x` like feature. The `trace` parameter of `trace.Trace` class enables line execution tracing. This class takes an `ignoredirs` parameter which is used to ignore tracing modules or packages located below the specified directory. I use it here to keep the tracer from tracing the `unittest` module.

test_has_perm_in_foobar.py

```
import sys
import trace
import unittest

from app import check_perm

tracer = trace.Trace(trace=1, ignoredirs=(sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix))

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        tracer.runctx('self.assertFalse(check_perm("dummy", 3))', globals(), locals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

app.py

```
def sub_check1(some_object):
    if some_object * 10 == 20:
        return True

def sub_check2(some_object):
    if some_object * 10 == 30:
        return True

def check_perm(request, some_object):
    if some_object == 1:
        return True
    if some_object == 2:
        return sub_check1(some_object)
    if some_object == 3:
        return sub_check2(some_object)
```

Test;

```
$ python test_has_perm_in_foobar.py 
 --- modulename: test_has_perm_in_foobar, funcname: <module>
<string>(1):   --- modulename: app, funcname: check_perm
app.py(10):     if some_object == 1:
app.py(12):     if some_object == 2:
app.py(14):     if some_object == 3:
app.py(15):         return sub_check2(some_object)
 --- modulename: app, funcname: sub_check2
app.py(6):     if some_object * 10 == 30:
app.py(7):         return True
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_one (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_has_perm_in_foobar.py", line 23, in test_one
    tracer.runctx('self.assertFalse(check_perm("dummy", 3))', globals(), locals())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/trace.py", line 513, in runctx
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

To make the code and the output even more shorter, just trace the required function alone.

```
import trace
import unittest

from app import check_perm

tracer = trace.Trace(trace=1)

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertFalse(tracer.runfunc(check_perm, 'dummy', 3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test;

```
$ python test_has_perm_in_foobar.py
 --- modulename: app, funcname: check_perm
app.py(10):     if some_object == 1:
app.py(12):     if some_object == 2:
app.py(14):     if some_object == 3:
app.py(15):         return sub_check2(some_object)
 --- modulename: app, funcname: sub_check2
app.py(6):     if some_object * 10 == 30:
app.py(7):         return True
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_one (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_has_perm_in_foobar.py", line 19, in test_one
    self.assertFalse(tracer.runfunc(check_perm, 'dummy', 3))
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.005s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following workflow? I read your `BTW` but hard rules sometimes stop us from solving our problems(especially if you are in an XY trap) so I'm going to suggest you use the debugger anyway.  I run into tests that fail all the time. When a full stack trace is critical to solving the problem, I use a combination of `pdb` and `py.test` to get the whole shebang. Considering the following program...

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.A
def test_add():

  a = 1
  b = 2

  add(a,b)

def add(a, b):
  assert a>b

  return a+b

def main():
  add(1,2)
  add(2,1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # execute only if run as a script
  main()
```

Running the command `py.test -v -tb=short -m A code.py` results in the following output...

```
art@macky ~/src/python/so-answer-stacktrace: py.test -v --tb=short -m A code.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.5 -- pytest-2.5.0 -- /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/python
collected 1 items

code.py:3: test_add FAILED

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_add ___________________________________
code.py:9: in test_add
>     add(a,b)
code.py:12: in add
>     assert a>b
E     assert 1 > 2
=========================== 1 failed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

One simple way to investigate the stack trace is to drop a `pdb` debug point in the test, `Mark` the individual test with a `pytest` mark, invoke that test, and inspect the stack inside the debugger. like so...

```
def add(a, b):
  from pdb import set_trace;set_trace()
  assert a>b

  return a+b
```

Now when I run the same test command again I get a suspended `pdb` debugger. Like so...

```
art@macky ~/src/python/so-answer-stacktrace: py.test -v --tb=short -m A code.py
=========================================================================================== test session starts ============================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.5 -- pytest-2.5.0 -- /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/python
collected 1 items

code.py:3: test_add
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PDB set_trace (IO-capturing turned off) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /Users/art/src/python/so-answer-stacktrace/code.py(13)add()
-> assert a>b
(Pdb)
```

If at this point I type the magic `w` for `where` and hit `enter` I see the full stack trace in all its glory...

```
(Pdb) w
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/py.test(9)<module>()
-> load_entry_point('pytest==2.5.0', 'console_scripts', 'py.test')()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/config.py(19)main()
-> return config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(376)__call__()
-> return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(387)_docall()
-> res = mc.execute()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(288)execute()
-> res = method(**kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/main.py(111)pytest_cmdline_main()
-> return wrap_session(config, _main)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/main.py(81)wrap_session()
-> doit(config, session)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/main.py(117)_main()
-> config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(376)__call__()
-> return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(387)_docall()
-> res = mc.execute()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(288)execute()
-> res = method(**kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/main.py(137)pytest_runtestloop()
-> item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(376)__call__()
-> return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(387)_docall()
-> res = mc.execute()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(288)execute()
-> res = method(**kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/runner.py(62)pytest_runtest_protocol()
-> runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/runner.py(72)runtestprotocol()
-> reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/runner.py(106)call_and_report()
-> call = call_runtest_hook(item, when, **kwds)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/runner.py(124)call_runtest_hook()
-> return CallInfo(lambda: ihook(item=item, **kwds), when=when)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/runner.py(137)__init__()
-> self.result = func()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/runner.py(124)<lambda>()
-> return CallInfo(lambda: ihook(item=item, **kwds), when=when)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/main.py(161)call_matching_hooks()
-> return hookmethod.pcall(plugins, **kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(380)pcall()
-> return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(387)_docall()
-> res = mc.execute()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(288)execute()
-> res = method(**kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/runner.py(86)pytest_runtest_call()
-> item.runtest()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/python.py(1076)runtest()
-> self.ihook.pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem=self)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/main.py(161)call_matching_hooks()
-> return hookmethod.pcall(plugins, **kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(380)pcall()
-> return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(387)_docall()
-> res = mc.execute()
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py(288)execute()
-> res = method(**kwargs)
  /Users/art/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/_pytest/python.py(188)pytest_pyfunc_call()
-> testfunction(**testargs)
  /Users/art/src/python/so-answer-stacktrace/code.py(9)test_add()
-> add(a,b)
> /Users/art/src/python/so-answer-stacktrace/code.py(13)add()
-> assert a>b
(Pdb)
```

I do a lot of work in frameworks. `pdb` + `where` gives you everything up to the actual entry point of the program. You can see buried in there my functions as well as the test runner's frames. If this were Django or Flask I would see all the stack frames involved with the internals of those frameworks.  Its my full stop gap for when things go really wrong.

If you have a test with lots of iterations or conditionals you might find yourself getting hung up on the same lines again and again. The solution is  to be clever about where you choose to instrument with `pdb`. Nesting it inside a conditional or instrumenting an iteration/recursion with a conditional(essentially saying *When this becomes `True` then suspend so I can inspect what is going on*). Furthermore `pdb` lets you look at all the runtime context(assignments, state, etc.)

For your case it looks like a creative instrumentation of `check_perm` is in order.

Comment: Yes, your solution works fine for the use case you explain. In your case the assertion is inside the method. If the assertion is after the method call, then the stacktrace does not reveal where the wrong value comes from. You would need to travel back in time to see the root of the problem. AFAIK this is not possible in pdb.

Comment: Sorry I just read this line `I know that I could use interactive debugging to find the matching line, but I am lazy and want to find a easier way to the line where check_perm() returned the return value.` So this is a waste of time. What's the answer? I don't know write your own editor/test runner combination? Submit a petition to change the laws of physics to something more convenient for you? Why ask such silly constrained questions.

Comment: this question got 14 up-votes. Why should I not ask silly questions? Maybe someone has a brilliant answer. How can I know without asking? I am curious: What do you think? BTW, someone told me that in c# you can do backwards step in the debugger! Maybe this question is not stupid, maybe you have never dared to dream that a debugger can do backwards steps :-) That's not physics, you even don't need DeepMind to solve this. At least readonly jumping back should be not that hard to implement.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking for a solution to your problem? Are you asking if anyone has bothered to build this obscure feature? Are you asking if its possible for this feature to be built? I can't say for sure but I feel its likely that the interpreter doesn't hang on to this sort of state and the tooling reflects those limitations.

Comment: I like the cut of your jib and I'm sorry if I come across as a bit of a boar, but if you really want to understand why its because you've fallen into the XY Trap(the most frustrating part of this site and perhaps professional software development). The hallmarks of this trap are... asking about a "problem" you have while simultaneously defining your desired solution. Whenever someone proposes a solution to your "problem"  you quickly amend the original question with a "BTW Thats not the solution I'm looking for check out my desired solution section for more details". Answers are impossible.

Comment: I am curious. What is an "XY trap" for you in general, and how does it apply here? The question starts with "I would love to see the last 10 lines which were executed by the python interpreter before this exception occured". The tools pytest, cgitb, ... don't show the last N lines executed by the python interpreter. They show the lines above the line of the stacktrace. Yes, I am hair-splitting, but sometimes you need to check the details :-)

Comment: Asking about your "solution" rather than your "problem". An example of a "problem" in your case is "I don't know which `case` is yielding a value". Your solution is "I'd like to peek into the execution history to see which `case` is the culprit." There are dozens of solutions to your problem, but you aren't interested in your problem you are interested in your solution. Imagine I ask "how do I get to your house?", but then say "I don't drive or ride in vehicles w/o tank treads, also can I land a chopper on your roof?" I'm not really asking for directions. I want to ride in a helicopter.

Comment: Yes,you are right. Up to now my (and your) solution (tracing) is my preferred answer. But how can I know that without asking? Maybe there is a better solution. AFAIK all people on stackoverflow are volunteers. People who like to answer question do it. People who don't like to do it, don't. Maybe I am blind, but I see no problem.

Comment: I don't really want to debate this in comments with you any further. So this is the last I'll say on it. Its not a problem *per se* its an etiquette breach(I'm sure you disagree, most breachers of etiquette do).  This is a Q&A site. The implication is that you ask a concise enough question to receive a reasonably concise answer. Your work needs to show that you've exhausted any obvious resources on the topic, it should be unique, and your question should be useful to others. My gut says you missed the mark on this one, but you got some answers and it looks like you fixed your issue so cheers!

Comment: Interesting chat, btw I really up voted this question because I learned the `trace` module. But how can a question be made so specific without interaction? I mean updating the question, because going through every comments is ... you know it!

Comment: @NizamMohamed `But how can a question be made so specific without interaction?` This is the definition of the "due diligence" aspect of SO. You should do at least enough on your own to formulate a specific question. Then your bit as the "asker" is over; its now time to sit back and reap the answers. The etiquette breach occurs in the back and forth. Where a question is asked, a reasonable solution is presented, then OP says "no, no my problem is more specific than that" and then edits the question to track towards the answer they really want. Its like editing history.